# Right metrics and loss for averaging label probabilities across an RNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to reproduce that in Keras:

> LRCN is trained to predict the
>   video’s activity class at each time step. To produce a single
>   label prediction for an entire video clip, we average the label
>   probabilities—the outputs of the network’s softmax layer—
>   across all frames and choose the most probable label.

But I am quite new to LSTMs and am not sure about which metrics and loss function to use to replicate the method applied in the text above.
So far I have an LSTM RNN, which returns sequences and its outputs I feed into a time-distributed dense layer of 3 classes.

A "frame" corresponds to a timestep of the RNN and `return_sequences=True` will enable me to return prediction per frame.

Could you please tell me which metrics and loss I need and if I need custom ones also?

Answer (score 0):

> Could you please tell me which metrics and loss I need and if I need custom ones also?

From the paper [document](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1411.4389.pdf)  you can see the work is old: May 2016.

Please consider some recent work with more specifics.

This paper, provides no clue on LSTM specifics except the variable number of units they used, so you may try to find models with explained metrics.